# Editing the /etc/launchd.conf file in OS X

Tags: macos, osx-lion, environment-variables

I am trying to run Android project using Maven in **Mac 10.7.4**, for that I need to set environment and path variables.

This are the steps I need to follow to run android using Maven

Maven 3.0.3+ installed,

> Set environment variable ANDROID_HOME to the path of your installed Android SDK and add $ANDROID_HOME/tools as well as $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools to your $PATH. (or on Windows %ANDROID_HOME%\tools and %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools).
>
> MacOS users: Note that for the path to work on the commandline and in IDE's started by launchd you have to set it in /etc/launchd.conf and NOT in .bashrc or something else

But I am very new to OS X so I don't know how to set it. I seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) but I get stuck in Step 4, saving the `etc/launchd.conf` file after entering the paths.

- How do I set environment variables globally?
- What do I need to open, edit, save the `etc/launchd.conf` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually need system-wide variables? If variables in your user environment would suffice you could create a directory `~/.MacOSX` and a file `environment.plist` in it, in case one of them doesn't exist, and then add your variables to `environment.plist`.

```
mkdir ~/.MacOSX
touch ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
open ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

Log off and back on for the changes to become active.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I don't think so. I will try environment.plist file. If could could you update how to add and save path to that file. Sorry i am very new to Mac]

Comment: The command `open ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` should open the file with the default application (normally the plist editor).

Comment: Yes i done that but i dont think it get added because while running my maven project it says  `Please provide a proper Android SDK directory path as configuration parameter <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> in the plugin <configuration/>. As an alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline: -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Did you log off and back on after adding the variables?

Answer (score 4):

You can use any editor to change the `/etc/launchd.conf` file, you don't have to use `vi` or `vim`.

Since you need superuser privileges to edit the file, you cannot simply run TextEdit. What you can do however is to open a Terminal and enter:

```
sudo touch /etc/launchd.conf
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /etc/launchd.conf
```

Now, TextEdit will open `/etc/launchd.conf`. Make your changes as explained in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) you mentioned. Make sure to replace the highlighted part with the actual path to your Android SDK, also changing your username.

> `setenv ANDROID_HOME /Users/your-username/Documents/android-sdk/`

Now save the file as usual through *File » Save* or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

A reboot might be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer slhck.. It helps when i use your first command it says launchd.conf file not found.. If possible could you update how to create as well. Many thanks

Comment: See my update to the question.

Comment: Done that slick, now it says The document “launchd.conf” could not be opened. You don’t have permission.

Comment: No, that can't be. Make sure to run both commands with `sudo`.

Comment: yes both commands are with sudo slhck

Answer (score 3):

You could also just open terminal and type `launchctl`

then `setenv <key> <value>`

which in your case woud be `setenv ANDROID_HOME /path/to/whatever`