# How to alter my mac os $PATH variable so that I can run the latest php version?

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

I've just followed this article (http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/) to update my php installation using HomeBrew.
The latest php version is indeed installed in /usr/local/bin
The problem is that my $PATH variable is the following (doing an echo $PATH reveals it) :

/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin

...so the old version of php (that comes with mountain lion) always run first

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: See [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion) and [How To Edit Your PATH Environment Variables On Mac OS X](http://hathaway.cc/2008/06/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: I have seen these links already but they don't answer my specific need.I don't want just to add a path to the $PATH variable.I want to know if I can change the order of the paths in the variable and if this action can harm the stability of my system.

Comment: You can simply add the path again, before the rest, in your bash profile. Changing it system-wide wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/481820/156043), if it doesn't already exist. Open the file in Plist Editor and add a variable `PATH` with a value `/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. Log off and back on so that the changes become effective.

Comment: There's no need to change the `environment.plist` just to change the path for shells. Editing `.bash_profile` is enough here. There's no Plist Editor by default on OS X, by the way.